# Z-Index for Sticky Navigation is not working

Tags: css

I'm developing my own theme with a sticky navigation that float in front of the content of the page.

My problem is even if I added this code, the stickynavigation div is still behind the wrapper.

```
.stickynavigation {
    width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: #FFF000;
        border-top: 2px solid #000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
        display: block;
        min-height: 60px;
        padding: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper {
        max-width:1000px;
        width:95%;
        margin:0 auto;
        position:relative;
        z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

`.stickynavigation` - contains the small logo and the navigation

`.wrapper` - contains the `<?php the_contents();?>`

any idea how to make it work? To make the Stickynavigation in front of all elements?

You may see my website with the issue i'm talking about here - 
https://thepassport.ph/how-to-apply-for-philippine-passport/

[image]

Thank you very much and appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need apply `z-index` on `sticky-wrapper` `div` like following:

```
.sticky-wrapper.is-sticky {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

**Explanation:** By default browsers set `z-index` order higher in last element and lower in first element in same sibling.

Suppose you have 3 elements in same sibling like following order then browser treat them:

```
<div>Element 1</div> // z-index: 1
<div> // z-index: 2
    Element 2
    <div>Sub element 1</div> // z-index: 1
    <div>Sub element 2</div> // z-index: 2
</div>
<div>Element 3</div> // z-index: 3
```

From above structure it is dose not matter how much `z-index` you set on `Sub element 1` element it will never come up above on `Element 3` until you set higher `z-index` explicitly in `Element 2`. Because `z-index` always compare first on sibling elements.

Also keep it mind to work properly `z-index` it is recommended to use `position: relative, absolute, fixed, sticky` etc.